# What is "Uncaught TopologyError: no outgoing dirEdge found" in Turf.js?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turfjs

I am attempting to use `turf.concave` to get a polygon. It works with most of the points I put in, but with one set of points, it takes offense and throws the following error:

`Uncaught TopologyError: no outgoing dirEdge found [ (-121.9717867, 47.73397465) ]`

The file with the data I am attempting to use is located [here](https://github.com/samcorcos/campaign-hawk/blob/master/precinct4.geojson).

The function is simply:

`turf.concave(<mygeojson>, 1, 'miles')`

And, as I said, it works with all the other FeatureCollections. Any idea why it wouldn't work with this one?